# How to avoid passing analytics down widget tree?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics, flutter-provider

I want track tab change in Flutter app with firebase analytics. In example app they are just pass FirebaseAnalyticsObserver down widget tree:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
        analytics: analytics,
        observer: observer,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.analytics, this.observer})
      : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(analytics, observer);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _MyHomePageState(this.analytics, this.observer);

  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
```

But problem is my tab page is far down widget tree. So it is hard to pass all the way down.

How I can initialise FirebaseAnalytics observer to track normal screen route but also provide it to tab page?

I am use Provider and ChangeNotifier. So maybe I can just initialise in a service and then provide this down? For example

```
class Analytic extends ChangeNotifier {

static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has InheritedWidget, a widget that does exactly that , it passes data all the way down , you can check the [official video showcase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t-8rBCGBYw) ,or some [articles](https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1).

To use it you wrap your widget with the inheritedwidget

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();//don't make this static please
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics); //don't make this static please

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ObserverProvider(
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'Firebase Analytics Demo'
      ),
    ),
    observer:observer,
    analytics:analytics
    )
    ;
  }
}


class ObserverProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const ObserverProvider(
      {Widget child,
      Key key,
      this.observer,
      this.analytics})
      : super(key: key, child: child);
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  static ObserverProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ObserverProvider));
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ObserverProvider e) => false;
}
```

and if you want to access the data , you call `ObserverProvider.of(context).observer` for the observer , and `ObserverProvider.of(context).analytics` for the analytics

Comment: Thanks for reply! I can initialise `Firebase analytics analytics` and `observer` in `ObserverProvider` ?

Comment: You can try, i would not suggest it since when it rebuilds it's gonna re-initialize everything and may lead to a memory leak .